# How to convert UTC-4 to US/Eastern in python?

Tags: python, time, timezone

I read time stamps from text file. These time stamps are in UTC-4. I need to convert them to US/Eastern.

```
import datetime
datetime_utc4 = datetime.datetime.strptime("12/31/2012 16:15", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

How do I convert it to US/Eastern? One-line answer would be best.

Note: my original question stated EST to EDT. But it does not change the essence of the question, which is how to go from one time zone to another. Upon some reading (following comments) I gather that python (pytz in particular) does not treat EST and EDT as separate time zones, rather as two flavors of US/Eastern. But this is an implementation detail. It is common to refer to EST and EDT as two different time zones, see e.g. [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html).

Comment: [tzinfo](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) class is used for this, as far as I know.

Comment: What EST would that be? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egypt_Standard_Time? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone? or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AEST?

Comment: Your timestamp is in *winter*, so this cannot be converted from standard to daylight saving time..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: EST and EDT are two different time zones. EST=UTC-5, EDT=UTC-4. You can always go from one to another, irrespective of time of year.

Comment: @user443854 - you are confusing time zones with offsets.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [time zone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Nobody is in EDT in the winter.  They may be in UTC-4 of some other zone though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your update and comments, I now understand that you have data that is fixed at UTC-4 and you want to correct this so that it is valid in US Eastern Time, including both EST/EDT where appropriate.  Here is how you do that with [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

dt = datetime.strptime("12/31/2012 16:15", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") \
             .replace(tzinfo = pytz.FixedOffset(-240)) \
             .astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
```

Note that I used the `America/New_York` time zone id.  This is the most correct form of identifier.  You could instead use `US/Eastern` and it would work just fine, but be aware that this is an alias, and it is just there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: You are making several assumptions about the origin of my input text file that are incorrect. One: it has nothing to do with daylight savings being disabled on host operating system. Two: there is no need to question the person who produced the file -- the time stamps on the file are incorrect (as a result of some strange interaction of Bloomberg Excel API and the person logging into their PC from remote location). I can see that the time stamps up to 3/8/13 are off by +1 hour, and after 3/8/13 they are correct. No need to go back to whomever produced the file. It can be fixed.

Comment: I realized that to correct my file, I need to convert from EDT (aka UTC-4) to US/Eastern. I updated my question.

Comment: Ahhhh..  Now we are getting somewhere.  It helps to know that you are trying to repair invalid data.  So you have static UTC-4 data, and you want to make sure that the times that should have been EDT are moved to it while the others are left alone.  Yes?

Comment: I would not call it invalid. I would call it UTC-4. I want to convert a timestamp recorded in UTC-4 to US/Eastern with daylight savings correctly applied where needed.

Comment: Well, whatever you want to call it, my edited answer is the solution you are asking for.